# Redirect to Play store

Tags: javascript, android

I want to redirect user to my Play Store application page, when they type some url in their mobile browser. I tried following code, but it redirect to play store website instead of Play Store app in android phone.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
    window.location = "http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example";
}
</script>
```

After some searching on google I found that I have to use market url. Than I changed code as follow. But still no luck. This code is not redirecting anywhere.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
    window.location = "market://details?id=com.example";
}
</script>
```

Can anyone help me to identify what I missed in this?

Comment: You can checkout the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser

Comment: @SailaLopa, I want my link to function like http://www.whatsapp.com/dl. To promote my application from website.

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://play.google.com/intl/en_us/badges/

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the following url :

https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html#OpeningPublisher

For example if I try browsing the following url mentioned in above site

http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps

it opens map app in playstore in my phone. The point is though the particular device should have playstore app installed.

Comment: Play store app is installed in my phone but it still not opening in app. It always open in website.

Comment: Did you set browser as default always ? Maybe thats the reason

Comment: No, because when I enter http://www.whatsapp.com/dl in browser than it took me to whatsapp applicaion page in Play store app.